# Dont include last child while using li:after

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to add "|" after every li elements but not include last li. How could I do?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/s9x05ks9/)

HTML

```
<nav class="footer-menu">
<ul>
   <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Page A</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.footer-menu ul li{display: inline-table;}
.footer-menu {text-align: center; background: #FFF;}
.footer-menu ul li:after {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
    width: 100%;
    content:"|";
}
```

Comment: In terms of the duplicate I mentioned you want to do: `.footer-menu ul li:not(:last-child):after { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
.footer-menu ul li{display: inline-table;}
.footer-menu {text-align: center; background: #FFF;}
.footer-menu ul li:not(:last-child):after {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
    width: 100%;
   content:"|";
}
```

```html
<nav class="footer-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Page A</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: *Note*: I'd recommend checking for duplicates first, this is a pretty common one.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks Spencer. Noted for the next time I see it.